# Multi-WHERE for two fields in different MySQL tables for a SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get results back if two cases match:

- table_users.Email='user@email.com'
- table_devices.DeviceUuid='51ec969c-8546-41f4-a748-ec2458c81d17'

But, I get empty results even though table_users.Email='user@email.com' exists!!!

```
SELECT table_users.Email, table_users.DeleteFlag, table_devices.DeviceUuid 
FROM table_users, table_devices 
WHERE table_users.Email='user@email.com' 
  OR table_devices.DeviceUuid='51ec969c-8546-41f4-a748-ec2458c81d17';
```

What am I missing...?  I'd rather not break this into two queries for performance reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: Are table_users and table_devices linked in any way? A foreign key? Maybe post the table structure. If they are linked, you need a join condition, if not, it should be separate queries.

Comment: 1st join. Then use `and` instead of `or`

Comment: what is the table structure table_users and table_devices?

Comment: TABLE users {Email, DeleteFlag}, TABLE devices {DeviceUuid}
I can't join the tables, because the whole point is to just check if one of the fields has the given value set... Even if that's the only field that has info in it.

I guess, I'll just have to do two separate select statements.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the only way to do this is definitely in two separate queries, because I'm checking to see if two things exist in two separate tables and there no way to join them, since one of them may not exist.

For the logic I need, two separate SELECT queries is the only solution apparently.

Thanks for the help anyways guys!

Answer (score 0):

Do your php code assume that just one record is returned, while in fact many may be returned?

If the two tables are not related in any way, you should use two queries to obtain the information you want. Without a join condition, your query will be far less efficient than using two separate queries, as you will get one record for each row not matched by your query.

If you insist on using just one query, try this:

```
SELECT Email, DeleteFlag, NULL AS DeviceUuid
FROM users
WHERE Email='user@email.com'
UNION
SELECT NULL AS Email, NULL AS DeleteFlag, DeviceUuid
FROM devices
WHERE DeviceUuid = '51ec969c-8546-41f4-a748-ec2458c81d17';
```

Your original query should also work if you change OR into AND, and if the given Device Uuid is found in the table.

Comment: This will return two rows, it should be `union all` instead. But I think simplier would be SELECT from users with subquery to select device uuid from devices.

Comment: @Zaffy Yes, it will return two rows, but using `union all` will not change that, as the two rows are not equal.  Also `union all` is the one that _retains_ duplicates.